# Dual Boot (Win 10 && Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows

Alright, i've read every single thread on here regarding this topic but still don't seem to be able to find any usefull answer.

Question:

I've had win10 installed and bootable on /dev/sdc and then installed
ubuntu 18.04 on /dev/sda (whole drive). Windows 10 now isn't recognized
at all, disk seems fine though.

What i've tried so far:

```
update-grub  // only adds default stuff to grub.cfg
os-prober    // gives no output at all
```

what else could i try to get it to recognize win10, also windows isn't booting anymore regardless of which disk i select on F8 boot-menu (just jumps into ubuntu nonetheless.

Comment: Please look through [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix), and edit your question to clearly explain how it's solutions failed when you tried them.

Comment: Are both systems installed in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues, especially with multiple drive installs (it installs grub to every drive if BIOS).
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually tried this over the past few days to find out that  the way you install windows 10 will affect into which mode UEFI vs. legacy you can run it. You can figure out whether you may have the same problem, by switching to legacy mode in BIOS, and see if you can boot into windows for trouble shooting purpose.

What worked for me, was to remake a live USB via Rufus on another windows computer to have a UEFI install on win10.Then created an empty partition on the new windows install. Then installed Ubuntu via live USB, selecting the empty partition.

Another problem might be the drive you select to boot into during Ubuntu install. Perhaps someone can help you with the selection when you install on two separate hard drives.